# How can I make a Bash alias that takes user input?

Tags: bash, alias, functions

I have a Bash alias for sending a command to my server like:

```
alias ssh=sshpass -p "Passw0rd!" ssh -p 9999 -q -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no user@192.168.1.15 "some_command"
```

but I want to be able to enter different commands (instead of a predefined command between quotation marks) each time, with a prompt for my input. Is that possible with some function?

Comment: See [Can I pass arguments to an alias command?](//askubuntu.com/q/626458)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's as easy as that:

```
myfunctionname(){
  sshpass -p "Passw0rd!" ssh -p 9999 -q -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no user@192.168.1.15 "$@"
}
```

This defines a function `myfunctionname` which uses the arguments you give it as the command(s) for `ssh`. Example calls:

```
myfunctionname tree
myfunctionname "ls -l; hostname"
myfunctionname ls -l\; pwd         # remember quoting if doing that!
```

Put the function in your `~/.bashrc` file to make it accessible from every new terminal.